# I got this error when I was trying to install brain.js with npm, I wrote npm i -S brain.js

Tags: npm, npm-install, brain.js

> I tried to install brain.js but it shows this monster looking error which I couldn't fid any solution by searching many times. I typed in my shell "npm i -S brain.js" but it shows this error.
> If anyone seeing this can help me, I will be very happy

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions 
may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See 
https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see 
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.1 found at "C:\Users\Tanbir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16  
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tanbir\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tanbir\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tanbir\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-08T18_38_19_827Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 3):

**The simplest way to solve it is by typing:**

```
npm install --save brain.js@1.4.10
```

This will install the lastest version from the releases page that works. This worked for me on Windows.

Comment: Then install stream to not have encounter with stream error `npm install stream`. Also after installing 1.4.10 you can upgrade the latest brain.js with no error

Answer (score 0):

I am figuring out how to solve the same issue.

Try to install Visual Studio first. The errormessage says it quite clearly: 'You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.'.

Once installed visual studio, in my case, the brain.js missed the gl library. Solution:

```
npm install --save -g gl
```

Finally I installed the brain.js via:

```
npm install --save -g brain.js
```

(the help from brain.js site doesn't use the -g "istall globally option")

Please consider I'm trying the solutions while I'm writing here, maybe I'm back later on with a better solution.

My view: the various element versions (npm, node.js, brain.js, the bound libraries etc. ) has been recently updated and somewhat something doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: It looks like you have a solution to this question, but are also raising a similar question of your own at the same time. Please edit your answer down to just the solution. I encourage you to raise a new question detailing the issue you are having. Doing this will have the benefits of making your answer more readable, and therefore likely to help more people, and your new question will hopefully get help with your issue